# Creating Controls.Add in Class

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and have a problem.

I have a created a class called All_Buttons and have a method inside it called create_button1().

This method creates a button called b1. At the end of the method I have added Controls.Add(b1).

Inside the class, Controls.Add(b1) gives an error but having the same method outside of the class works fine.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Below is the code but for some reason only the last method is showing the way it should.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        class All_Buttons
        {
            void create_button1()
            {
                Button b1 = new Button();
                b1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                b1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                b1.Visible = true;
                b1.Text = "Button1";
                //Does not work//
                Control.Add(b1);
            }
        }

        void create_button1()
        {
            Button b1 = new Button();
            b1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            b1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            b1.Visible = true;
            b1.Text = "Button1";
            //This works//
            Control.Add(b1);
        }
```

Comment: @wazz Please avoid correcting the code. That missing semicolon could be causing an issue.

Comment: I didn't touch a semicolon. Ah, I think I added a brace. I'll revert.

Comment: On top of Nisarg's comment, Controls.Add() will be a function available inside Form1 class derived from base class Form. All_Buttons will not have access to Controls element of a form.

Comment: That `All_Buttons` class is not needed here. This is the reason why you cannot access `Control`.

Comment: The variable Control is probably the issue.  The method that isn't working doesn't have access to the variable.  Normally you use This.Controls.Add(b1).  You do not have the 's' on the variable name so you must have a variable called Control.  The first method 'this' would refer to the class object All_Buttons which the second method 'this' would refer to the form which has a built in object called Controls (with the 's').

Comment: It is normally helpful to write `this.Controls.Add(b1);`  Makes IntelliSense useful and aids your brain in realizing it is the form object that you add the control to.  Do that in create_button as well and it now becomes obvious, All_buttons is not a form so does not have a Controls property.  `this` can no longer work, you need a different object reference.  Pass it through the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access `Control` from within a nested class. You'd need to pass the `Form1` instance to the `All_Buttons` class, via a ctor or a parameter to `create_button1` for example, to be able to access it.

```
    class All_Buttons
    {
        void create_button1(Form1 form)
        {
            Button b1 = new Button();
            b1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            b1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            b1.Visible = true;
            b1.Text = "Button1";

            form.Controls.Add(b1);
        }
    }
```

But in this case I'd recommend you redesign your structure, as it seems there's no need for a nested class.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I just copy-pasted OP's code. Edited to `Controls`.

Comment: Thanks for this V0ldek, How would I access the create_button1 method from the Form1 : Form class? I tried: